# Node References, new Node button for the referenced Node

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm using [References Module](http://drupal.org/project/references) + [cnr module](http://drupal.org/project/cnr) for having bidirectional node references between two different node types (Say Brand and Product).
So Brand can have many products but product has only one brand.

I want a "Create Product" button in the Brand page, that opens up a form to create a product where the Brand relationship/reference is **already defined**. What's the best way to do this? (in the other scenario of a "regular" add content, it should have the select control to choose the Brand from a list (or the auto-complete, doesn't matter)

Also, I would like to NOT display the list of referenced products in the Brand Create/Edit form, I do want them to be displayed on the rendered node page as a list.

As a side question (since this combination is already working for me), since it was anounced the References module is on its way out, and to be replaced by [Entity Reference module](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) - what would be the best way to achieve the same functionality using *that* module (just found [This module](http://drupal.org/project/ref_field) ) which might be what I was looking for.

Comment: No one? I can't be the first developer looking into this...

Comment: Try node connect to add directly products to your brand: http://drupal.org/project/nodeconnect